# Dark beamer theme, should I redefine a complete template?

Tags: beamer

I have just defined a new .sty to make presentations following my Uni's graphical chart. However, my supervisor prefers dark themes over light themes. I would like to go the extra mile here, but I am not sure about the approach: should I define another _dark.sty? Or is it a better idea (I think it might be if feasible), to pass this styling as an option to a single template?

As a MWE, please consider the great work of https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports, which (heavily) helped me getting started in a simple manner. My template is not as sharp as his right now (though it's publicly accessible too).

For instance, I would like to start with his "Klope" theme. What would be a smart way to implement an option allowing for darker greens to be used?

Comment: You do not define that in one .sty file. You have a structured theme and may provide multiple *color themes*. Have a look at the Metropolis theme to see how the file layout might look.

Comment: Just as @TeXnician said, I would pass dark as a option to your theme and within your theme either load the matching colour theme (if you structured your theme unlike the ones which you linked to) or do your definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. For my exchange in Purdue I wanted a black/gold theme. I just used `\setbeamercolor`:

```
\definecolor{satinsheengold}{rgb}{0.8, 0.63, 0.21}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=satinsheengold}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=satinsheengold}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=satinsheengold}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{bg=satinsheengold}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{bg=satinsheengold}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
```

This way you can redefine every element. Hope it helps

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).